# In sensenet (v 7.0.0) after add new user content explorer shows a 404 page

Tags: sensenet

Under IMS folder in content explorer after adding new user and press save button i see thes page 
[image]

But after reopen the folder i see new added user.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue is caused by an incorrectly called action method which did not receive the correct back url parameter. As this value is used when redirecting the page after the operation, it is essential to the page flow. So actually the user creation executed correctly, but the the user was redirected to an incorrect target url and this resulted in a 404 response.

[The issue](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/issues/236) is already fixed in [sensenet 7.0.1](https://github.com/SenseNet/sensenet/releases/).